# Media Query for an image not working correctly

Tags: html, css, media-queries

In my project I want to move my image if the screen size gets to a certain width. At the moment, the image stays in a static position and I am not to sure why.

Here is my code:

```
 <div style="height: 630px; width: 350px;" class="formContainer" >
```

CSS:

```
 @media screen and (max-width: 1332px) {
     .formContainer {
         left: 100;
         top: 40px;
     }
}
```

However if I set the left property to 0, the div moves, however I do not want to move the div that far. Does anybody know the issue?

Comment: you are missing units on your `left` property. `100` what? px? Also, you'll need to set a position on that element, e.g. `'position: relative'`. Also, you have it set to `max-width`, so that element will be in that position until the window width is larger than 1332px.

Comment: @disinfor Hello, so I dont quite understand this max-width element. How would I implement it in my code, and what is it used for. May you give me some example code using it?

Comment: The issue is 0 is not the same as 100.

Comment: What do you mean? Is it the `media query` that you do not understand? What are you trying to do with the image element?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This snippet could point you in the right direction:

```
.formContainer {
  position: relative;  // position is 'static' by default
  left: 100px;  // you missed unit here (was 'left: 100')
  top: 40px;
}
```

First, you did not specify unit for the `left` attribute. When you use value `0`, unit can indeed be ommited, because zero of any unit is still just a zero. If you use value other than zero, like `100`, you need to specify the unit, because it now makes a difference whether it is `100px` or `100rem`.

Second, the position is by default `static`. `left` and `top` don't have any effect on statically positioned elements. For your use case, I think the `relative` position is a good fit instead.

Comment: Ah, how would I implement the max-width attribute in the example snippet above. What is it used for?

Comment: It is fairly simple. If you wrap some CSS styling rules inside of @media query which says (max-width: 1332px), it tells the browser that these rules should only apply when the width of the screen is <= 1332px.

Comment: @ajobi please add that into the answer and not just a comment.

Comment: @eweee glad to help ;-) there is also `min-width` which works the other way around, and is more common in building responsive designs in general. (min-width: 1332px) would mean that the rule will apply only to screens with width >= 1332px.

Comment: @eweee also, if you think my answer solved your problem, you can mark it as correct. This way everyone knows your question already has a solution, and I get a little reputation as a reward for helping you ;-)

Comment: @ajobi Sure! I have